# Updating statistics in multiple child nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, updating

I am Creating a Soccer Fantasy Web App and am currently concerned that Firebase might not be the right back-end service to use. In my Realtime Database Tree, there are 2 nodes:

1. The Players node- which contains a fire base array of 49 players. Each player is a java script object converted into a JSON object in the JSON array.
2. The users node- which contains the details of each user after being created using the fireabseAuth method.

In the local server, there is an empty array. What I have done is to get each user to make a 6- player selection which fills up the empty array. Once full, the array will then be saved on the real time database under the users node.

My Issue

My issue is how to get each players' stats updated in the players node such that the updated stats in the players node will be reflected under each user's selections in the users node.
Is this possible with firebase at all? I hope it is because I really want to take advantage of the realtime syncing between the database and the client side server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about architecture.

Just make it so that when the user selects a player, a reference is stored on their node. Then whenever you're querying a users selection, you can just grab the ids within their selection and grab player from the players node by the ids.

E.G.

```
Users {
    John: {
        Selection: [1,2,3]
    },
    Mark: {
        Selection: [1,2,4]
    } 
}

Players {
    1: {
        name: 'Messi',
        agility: 90
    },
    2: {
        name: 'Beckham',
        agility: 54
    },
    3: {
        name: 'Rooney',
        agility: 10
    },
    4: {
        name: 'Neymar',
        agility: 84
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Would that mean that when i change , say Messi's agility in the Players node, it will automatically update in the users node for John under selection [1]?

Comment: Yes :) If you're grabbing data on the client then you need to make sure that when the node changes, your client will receive the changes live (or until they refresh the page where it will grab the data from fresh). You can do this by basically listening for changes on the player nodes that the user has selected.

Comment: thanks, I have tried writing some listening code and it hasnt worked perfectly but I will try again.

Comment: as i had already imported the JSON file of the 49 players, is there a way that I can then add ids to each players manually or would i have to remake the 49 player list adding IDs?

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi you can modify the data in the firebase console or build a ui that modifies the data from your application.

Comment: thanks a bunch. Another problem I am encountering, is storing the array from the client side directly to the firebase database. Is this the wrong way to go about it? maybe i should be storing the selection from the players array directly to the users array, instead of storing the selections to the client side empty array and THEN storing the array to the users node.